# Sequelize transaction failing when using JSON API response

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize transactions to make sure each query is working off of the most recent data. I am using Express to return the SQL response.

Edit: (I used a better benchmarking tool and I don't think my old question was addressing the actual problem). My understanding of transactions was that Sequelize would run one transaction at a time, instead of running multiple in parallel. Is that not the case here? If so, would I need to use some locking mechanisms?

```
const test_create_transaction = async (serviceID, res) => {
  try {
    return sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
      let serviceRoom;
      // Find a service room with less than a certain number of customers
      serviceRoom = await ServiceRooms.findOne({
        where: {
          serviceID,
          numberCustomers: {
            [Op.lt]: MAX_CUSTOMERS_PER_ROOM,
          },
        },
        transaction: t,
      });
      // If no such room exists, create a new room
      if (!serviceRoom) {
        serviceRoom = await ServiceRooms.create(
          {
            serviceID,
          },
          { transaction: t }
        );
      }
      const testUserUID = "testUID" + Date.now().toString();
      const { serviceRoomUID } = serviceRoom;
      // Add the customer to that room
      await ServiceRoomEnrollments.create(
        {
          serviceRoomUID: serviceRoomUID,
          userUID: testUserUID,
          serviceID: serviceID,
        },
        { transaction: t }
      );
      // Increment the number of customers in that room
      await ServiceRooms.increment("numberCustomers", {
        by: 1,
        transaction: t,
        where: {
          serviceRoomUID: serviceRoomUID,
        },
      });
      // PROBLEM: For some reason, the very first findOne query does not use 
      // the up to date number of customers.
      return res.send(“test”);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error.message);
    res.end();
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?